# Sheets - Return TRUE if value from list is found

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns in Google Sheets, A,B with a long list of words. Something like this:

```
A: Red, yellow, blue

C: Extra
```

​
I also have an empty cell, D1, to type in. And E2 to show the result.

What I need is a formula that will return TRUE in E2 whenever any of the values from column A are found by themselves or combined with values from column C. However, if only a value from C is found or a word from outside the list it should return FALSE.

There can be one or more values from column A, separated by a " + " sign.

So for example, if I type some values in D1 his is the result I would expect:

- Red -> TRUE
- Red + Yellow -> TRUE
- Yellow + Extra -> TRUE
- Extra -> FALSE
- Blue + Red + Dog -> FALSE
- Dog + Extra -> FALSE
- Cat + Dog -> FALSE
- Red + Yellow + Blue + Extra -> TRUE

So to summarise, if the values are from:

```
Column A (one or several values): TRUE

Column C: FALSE

Column A + COLUMN C (one or several values): TRUE

Any other combination or random words from outside of the list: FALSE
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I've been trying and trying but I am not there yet.
Thanks!

Comment: Why `Purple` is false while `Yellow + Purple` is true?

Comment: Because column C by itself should return false. But C + A should return TRUE

Comment: If one of the words don't match with any column it should return FALSE?

Comment: I updated the question to make it clearer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: I used MAP to search each splitted value in A:C with FLATTEN. This way, each MATCH from a column would have an equal remainder divided by 3, so MOD would work for determining column in each value. If there's no match, then with IFERROR it returns 0

Now, this series of numbers I put them in a LAMBDA she called it *range* to be more manageable. If COUNTIF of 0 (no match) and 2 (ColB) it's greater than 0, it will return FALSE. Then it checks if there's a 1, if it does then it will be TRUE, or else FALSE ,(meaning the values would be only from ColC). Here you have a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11gY3RAtYB-ZgMLSSvB7an7M_Z5Ga-tWJpVGK4PYLbYw/edit#gid=0)

```
=lambda(range,IF(COUNTIF(range,0)+COUNTIF(range,2),FALSE,IF(COUNTIF (range,1),TRUE,FALSE)))(map(split(SUBSTITUTE(D1," ",),"+",1,1),LAMBDA(n,IFERROR(mod(MATCH(n,FLATTEN(A:C),0)-1,3)+1,0))))
```

Comment: It was meant for your previous conditions with ColB. I don't know if you'll have it or not, but check if it is useful!

Comment: Hey! It is perfect, considering my previous conditions so I will just adapt it. Great work thanks!